# AngularJS access $scope variable outside of the then callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I invoke a method from my Bootstrap Modal submit button as below;

```
$scope.addProject = function() {
    $http.post('/cc-addProject' , $scope.project).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $('#myModal').modal('toggle'); 
        $scope.dataList = response.data;
      }, function errorCallback(response) {     
      });
    console.log("$scope.dataList : " + $scope.dataList); // I cannot access the same response.data here
};
```

Also this is how I invoke the addProject() in my views

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right"  style="margin-left:10px;" ng-click="addProject()" ng-if="selectedID == -1">Sumbit</button>
```

I want to access the "response.data" which I set for $scope.dataList inside the then callback outside
Currently it does not live update the grid with the above code.

How do I do that ?

***********Relevant grid code*********

```
<tbody>                             
    <tr role="row" class="odd" ng-repeat="project in dataList">
        <td>{{project.projectName}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Try to print the `$scope.dataList` in success callback. It should work

Comment: You currently access your `$scope.dataList` outside with `console.log("$scope.dataList : " + $scope.dataList); `, what is the question? Maybe the problem is that you using jQuery libs? Why dont you use bootstrap-ui?

Comment: I can access $scope.dataList inside the callback, but I need to access/set outside of it

Comment: @testndtv that should update your grid. Please provide your grid's html

Comment: Updated the relevant grid code

Comment: try to print `console.log(response.data)` and provide the output

Comment: print the `dataList` in your HTML template and check whether it is updating after service call

Comment: `$http.post` is asynchronous, which means the callback (any code in the `then` function) will be called some time later once the request has finished. Your line `console.log` executes before your `then` callback is called, so the values in `$scope.dataList` hasn't been set when you try to access it. There's no way around it, you need to read up on working with promises and asynchronous code.

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else but its unable to solve as long as the user does not give enough information about his problem & do not answer users questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because problem is somewhere else but can't be solved as long as the user does not give enough information about his problem & does not answer users questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't log directly the updated value of `$scope.dataList` because `$http.post` is a `async function`, but you really want to access it from outside the you need to invoke a function from success callback of `$http.post` Eg.

```
$scope.addProject = function() {
    $http.post('/cc-addProject' , $scope.project).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $('#myModal').modal('toggle'); 
        $scope.dataList = response.data;
        useUpdatedValue();
      }, function errorCallback(response) {     
    });

    function useUpdatedValue() {
      console.log("$scope.dataList : " + $scope.dataList); // I cannot access the same response.data here
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't no why you vote down my answer, because this is the way to access the updated value from async function, I think you are not aware about async, so please first ready it carefully then do anything else

Comment: This code doesnt make sense at all. It just creates a not needed function used as a callback. This could also be placed inside the resolve part of $http. He is still not able to handle the callback "outside" the $http success part.

Comment: @testndtv If `dataList` is not updating in your template, you have a scoping issue. Modals create scopes. Maybe the `dataList` is going onto the wrong scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a watcher for dataList outside of the callback. When the response.data returns, dataList is updated. Then the code in the watcher's callback will run.

Comment: Let me ask you...the way I have "dataList" in my html template....why would it not refresh automatically if dataList changes ?

Comment: @testndtv If `dataList` is not updating in your template, you have a scoping issue. Modals create scopes. Maybe the `dataList` is going onto the wrong scope.

Comment: @brickinup It is better to **chain** data from a promise. Watchers execute every digest cycle and slow down the framework.

Comment: if template is not updated automatically, it may be a scope issue like georgeawg said. @georgeawg yes you are right. Watchers will slow down the app, but one or two watchers don't hurt:) Actually, if dataList is bound in template with two way binding, angular has already created a watcher for it. So creating another watcher is not necessary.